# How to load application context in JUnit and use Autowired

Tags: spring, junit, autowired, applicationcontext

I'm writing JUnit test.

How can I load application context to make annotation Autowired works?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the Spring dos. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html may be a good starting point.